# Creating OAuth2RestTemplate Resource with Proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, proxy

I'm trying to create an Client that is using OAuth2 but also needs to travers thru a proxy. Currently I'm getting the error `Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Factory method 'restTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException` I'm not sure how because I'm using the `@Bean`annotation on the method to make sure IoC container is aware, is this not correct? See two methods being used for this below:

```
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws JSONException {
        AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(restTemplateResource(),
                new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr));


        //Proxy Settings
        LOG.error("--in getProxySettings-");
        LOG.info(System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));
        JSONObject vcapServices = new JSONObject(System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"));
        LOG.info("vcapServices {}",vcapServices.toString());
        JSONObject cproxy = vcapServices.getJSONArray("c-proxy").getJSONObject(0);
        LOG.info("cproxy {}",cproxy.toString());
        JSONObject credentials = cproxy.getJSONObject("credentials");
        LOG.info("credentials {}",credentials.toString());

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(credentials.getString("host"), credentials.getInt("port")),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(credentials.getString("username"), credentials.getString("password"))
        );

        HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost(credentials.getString("host"), credentials.getInt("port"));
        HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();

        clientBuilder.setProxy(myProxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).disableCookieManagement();

        HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
        return restTemplate;
    }



    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails restTemplateResource() {

        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(websecSecurityDetails.getEndpoint());
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientId(websecSecurityDetails.getClientId());
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setClientSecret(websecSecurityDetails.getClientSecret());
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setGrantType(websecSecurityDetails.getGrantType());
        List<String> scopeList = new ArrayList<>();
        scopeList.add(websecSecurityDetails.getScope());
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setScope(scopeList);
        clientCredentialsResourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
        return clientCredentialsResourceDetails;
    }
```

Comment: >> nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
The bean can't be instantiated because of the exception thrown in it. Check again the stack trace where exactly the exception happend.

Answer (score 0):

This was because app was not deployed in env so "VCAP_SERVICES" java ops was not available.